# I have scanned a document containing table. How do I export this table to excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, pdf, scanning

I have a document with various tables on it that I have scanned, yielding very clear jpeg images. Is it possible for some sort of text-recognition software to able to read the tables and allow me to export them to an excel spread sheet? I'm assuming I would need to somehow convert to pdf first.

Comment: Found this, but can't speak to how well it works (have never used it): http://www.onlineocr.net/

Comment: ABBYY FineReader

Comment: You have this tagged `pdf` do you have acrobat? It can save as excel.

Answer (score -1):

You can convert to text by pasting it into One Note.  Then you should be able to drop into excel, you

Comment: I think you're missing a word or two? Can you maybe expand your answer to add some detailed instructions or even screenshots?